# synchronized block inside onReceive() callback

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am reading [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html) about how to program Android to talk to a USB accessory. One of the steps involves registering a `BroadcastReceiver` to obtain permission from the user:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

where `mUsbReceiver` is defined as:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(accessory != null){
                        //call method to set up accessory communication
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for accessory " + accessory);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What puzzles me is why `synchronized (this)` is used? `onReceive()` will be called on the UI thread and that's it. This block of code does not seem to touch any data which may be accessed by other threads, unless the object `accessory` counts (and there's nothing on the page that suggests it is).

I searched on the web, and there does not seem to be much emphasis on thread-safety in `onReceive()` (it's called by a very specific thread after all). Am I missing something?

**Update: I want to stress that I know what `synchronized (this)` does, because some comments below seem to suggest I don't. What I don't understand is why it was used in the above code fragment, which seems unnecessary.**

Comment: Obviously I didn't make myself clear. I *know* what `synchronized (this)` means and I know `this` refers to the BroadcastReceiver object itself. What I don't understand is why it was used in the above context, which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onReceive()` will not always be called on a UI thread. If `BroadcastReceiver` is registered using an overload of `registerReceiver()` which accepts a `Handler scheduler` param, then `onReceive()` callback will be executed on a thread, that handler has been attached to. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler)):

> `Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)`
>
> Register to receive intent broadcasts, to run in the context of *scheduler*. **scheduler** is a handler identifying the thread that will receive the `Intent`. If null, the main thread of the process will be used.

Nevertheless, particularly in the case outlined in the docs there is no need to wrap any code into a `synchronized` block, because the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered using standard [`registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) overload, which is guarantees to fire `onReceive()` callback on UI thread.

I think that's merely a showcase code, that demonstrates how to correctly write an `onReceive()` implementation, taking care of all the edge cases. If the author of that doc hadn't written `synchronized` block I wouldn't know, that it's possible to make `onReceive()` to be executed on a thread other than UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figure too (that `synchronized (this)` may not have a serious meaning in this case). Thanks for confirming.